# Issues setting ringtone in android 10

Tags: android, ringtone, ringtonemanager

After the deprecation of `getContentUriForPath()` and `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` i modified the code as below :

```java
 private boolean SetAsRingtone(File k)
    {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, k.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        Uri newUri=this.getContentResolver()
                .insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Emotes.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                newUri);

        return true;
    }
```

The problem is that the ringtone of the device does not change. I can see from the sound setting that it changed but when the phone rings the default music plays.

Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: I think the problem is that the URI returned by the audio media store doesn't have the ringtone file associated with it. As you say, the DATA column was deprecated, and it's no longer possible to insert a record in the audio media store with a path to the file. Instead, I believe you have to do the insert, then write the content of the file to the URI returned. Perhaps have a look at this link and see if it helps?  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item

Comment: Did you resolve it @lbrahim?

Comment: @PhanSinh yes i have posted the answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58255532/how-to-set-a-file-as-a-ringtone-for-android-10/59309578#59309578

although its a bit outdated

Comment: @Ibrahim Thanks for your responding. I have got this error `Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media`

My file have stored in this path: `File(context.getExternalFilesDir("ringtones"), "ringtone_123.mp3")` and I did allow the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

My project have build on target api 30.

Do you know what's problem there?