# Unable to set Ringtone/Notification Tone Programmatically in Android-11

Tags: android, mediastore, android-11, scoped-storage, ringtonemanager

I already know this question has been asked many times and answered, But this is something different. I am trying to set a Tone in android-11 and tried all the possible solutions over the internet and SO.

The most helpful question and answer which I found is [How to set a file as a ringtone for Android 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58255532/how-to-set-a-file-as-a-ringtone-for-android-10) but still, I couldn't make it happen.

The thing is I am able to save my **raw** folder.mp3 file to local storage in my phone but when I try to set this as a tone I am getting exceptions and I am unable to set it. I have tried putting log and all only this below 2 lines not getting executed. If anyone can help that would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(MainActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
```

I have already given storage permission and also runtime checked about all the permission. Also i have set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

my whole code

```
InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ring);
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fIn.available()];
        fIn.read(buffer);
        fIn.close();
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES) + "/Tone/";
        String filename = "Ring.mp3";

        if (!new File(path).exists()) {
            new File(path).mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
            save.write(buffer);
            save.flush();
            save.close();
            sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE", Uri.parse("file://" + path + filename)));

            File k = new File(path, filename);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "RingTone");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, Boolean.valueOf(true));
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, Boolean.valueOf(false));
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, Boolean.valueOf(false));
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, Boolean.valueOf(false));

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
            getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
            Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(MainActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
            return true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

Also i have tried with another method but getting same result like unable to set as ringtone

```
Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        try (OutputStream os = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newUri)) {
            //copy your file from asset into os here
            int size = (int) f.length();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
            try {
                BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
                buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                buf.close();

                os.write(bytes);
                os.close();
                os.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```